# Unable to fetch deeply nested hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this rake task which uses rest-client to fetch some messy JSON from this API, and then uses [hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) to make the code prettier.

Unfortunately I'm unable to fetch one of the deeply nested values, `productGroup`. If working correctly, it should output `:category => "Jeans"` or similar. Please see the JSON at the bottom.

This did not work:

```
mash.deep_fetch(:fields, 0).deep_locate(-> (key, value, object) { value.include?("product_group") }) { "ERROR: category" }
```

Example output:

```
% rake get_products
{:category=>nil, :name=>"Luxurous Jumpsuit", :image=>"http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/129579-0012.jpg", :price=>"599", :description=>"Lorem ipsum dolor"}
```

Example mash:

```
#<Hashie::Mash brand="Dr Denim" categories=[#<Hashie::Mash name="Kvinne > KLÆR > Jeans > Slim">] description="Lorem ipsum dolor." fields=[#<Hashie::Mash name="sale" value="false">, #<Hashie::Mash name="product_id_original" value="226693-7698">, #<Hashie::Mash name="gender" value="Kvinne">, #<Hashie::Mash name="artNumber" value="226693-7698">, #<Hashie::Mash name="productGroup" value="Jeans">, #<Hashie::Mash name="productStyle" value="Slim">, #<Hashie::Mash name="extraImageProductSmall" value="http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/cart_thumb/226693-7698.jpg">, #<Hashie::Mash name="productClass" value="Klær">, #<Hashie::Mash name="extraImageProductLarge" value="http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/226693-7698.jpg">, #<Hashie::Mash name="sizes" value="W24/L32,W25/L32,W26/L32,W27/L32,W28/L32,W29/L32,W30/L32,W31/L32,W32/L32,W26/L30,W27/L30,W28/L30,W29/L30,W24/L30,W25/L30,W32/L30,W31/L30,W30/L30">, #<Hashie::Mash name="color" value="Mid Blue">] identifiers=#<Hashie::Mash sku="226693-7698"> language="no" name="Regina Jeans" offers=[#<Hashie::Mash feed_id=10086 id="2820760a-c5b2-494a-b5dd-ab713f796cb9" in_stock=1 modified=1474947357838 price_history=[#<Hashie::Mash date=1474949513421 price=#<Hashie::Mash currency="NOK" value="599">>] product_url="http://pdt.tradedoubler.com/click?a1234" program_logo="http://hst.tradedoubler.com/file/17833/2014-logos/200X200.png" program_name="Nelly NO" source_product_id="226693-7698">] product_image=#<Hashie::Mash url="http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/226693-7698.jpg">>
```

get_products.rake:

```
# encoding: utf-8

# Gets messy JSON from other store via REST client and cleans it up with Hashie

require "rest_client"
require "hashie"

Product = Struct.new(:category, :name, :image, :price, :description)

module ProductsFromOtherStore
  CATEGORIES = [
    "festkjoler",
    "jakker",
    "jeans",
    "jumpsuit",
    "vesker"
  ]

  def self.fetch
    CATEGORIES.map do |category|
      Tradedoubler.fetch category
    end
  end

  # Prettify, ie. `fooBar` => `foo_bar`

  def self.prettify(x)
    case x
    when Hash
      x.map { |key, value| [key.underscore, prettify(value)] }.to_h
    when Array
      x.map { |value| prettify(value) }
    else
      x
    end
  end
end

class ProductsFromOtherStore::Tradedoubler
  KEY = "FE34B1309AB749F1578AEE87D9D74535513F6B54"

  # Products to fetch from API

  LIMIT = 2

  def self.fetch category
    new(category).filtered_products.take(LIMIT)
  rescue RestClient::RequestTimeout => e
    Array.new
  end

  def initialize category
    @category = category

    # API doesn't support gender or category searches, so do some filtering based on available JSON fields

    @filters = Array.new

    define_filter { |mash|
      mash.fields.any? { |field|
        field.name == "gender" && field.value.downcase == "kvinne"
      }
    }

    define_filter { |mash|
      mash.categories.any? { |category|
        category.name.underscore.include? @category
      }
    }
  end

  def define_filter(&filter)
    @filters << filter
  end

  def filtered_products
    filtered_mashes.map { |mash|
      # puts mash

      Product.new(
        # mash.deep_fetch(:fields, 0).find { |field| field[:name] == "product_group" }[:value],
        mash.deep_fetch(:fields, 0).deep_locate(-> (key, value, object) { value.include?("product_group") }) { "ERROR: category" },
        mash.deep_fetch(:name) { "ERROR: name" },
        mash.deep_fetch(:product_image, :url) { "ERROR: image URL" },
        mash.deep_fetch(:offers, 0, :price_history, 0, :price, :value) { "ERROR: price" },
        mash.deep_fetch(:description) { "ERROR: description" }
      )
    }
  end

private
  def request
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/products.json;q=#{ URI.encode(@category) };limit=#{ LIMIT }?token=#{ KEY }",
      :timeout => 0.4
    )
  end

  def hashes
    ProductsFromOtherStore.prettify(JSON.parse(request)["products"])
  end

  def mashes
    hashes.map { |hash| Hashie::Mash.new(hash) }.each do |mash|
      mash.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepFetch
      mash.extend Hashie::Extensions::DeepLocate
    end
  end

  def filtered_mashes
    mashes.select { |mash| mash_matches_filter? mash }
  end

  def mash_matches_filter? mash

    # `.all?` requires all filters to match, `.any?` requires only one

    @filters.all? { |filter| filter.call mash }
  end
end

# All that for this

task :get_products => :environment do
  @all_products_from_all_categories = ProductsFromOtherStore.fetch

  @all_products_from_all_categories.each do |products|
    products.each do |product|
      puts product.to_h
    end
  end
end
```

The messy JSON we got via rest-client:

```
{
    "productHeader": {
        "totalHits": 367
    },
    "products": [{
        "name": "501 CT Jeans For Women",
        "productImage": {
            "url": "http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/441576-1056.jpg"
        },
        "language": "no",
        "description": "Jeans fra Levi's. Noe kortere nederst, fem lommer. Normal høyde på midjen, med hemper i linningen og knappegylfen. Dekorative slitte partier foran og nederst på benet.<br />Laget av 100% bomull.",
        "brand": "Levis",
        "identifiers": {
            "sku": "441576-1056"
        },
        "fields": [{
            "name": "sale",
            "value": "false"
        }, {
            "name": "sizes",
            "value": "W24/L32,W25/L32,W26/L32,W27/L32,W28/L32,W29/L32,W30/L32,W31/L32,W25/L34,W26/L34,W27/L34,W28/L34,W29/L34,W30/L34"
        }, {
            "name": "productStyle",
            "value": "Straight"
        }, {
            "name": "gender",
            "value": "Kvinne"
        }, {
            "name": "product_id_original",
            "value": "441576-1056"
        }, {
            "name": "productGroup",
            "value": "Jeans"
        }, {
            "name": "extraImageProductLarge",
            "value": "http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/441576-1056.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "extraImageProductSmall",
            "value": "http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/cart_thumb/441576-1056.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "artNumber",
            "value": "441576-1056"
        }, {
            "name": "productClass",
            "value": "Klær"
        }, {
            "name": "color",
            "value": "Indigo"
        }],
        "offers": [{
            "feedId": 10086,
            "productUrl": "http://pdt.tradedoubler.com/click?a(2402331)p(80279)product(57d37b9ce4b085c06c38c96b)ttid(3)url(http%3A%2F%2Fnelly.com%2Fno%2Fkl%C3%A6r-til-kvinner%2Fkl%C3%A6r%2Fjeans%2Flevis-441%2F501-ct-jeans-for-women-441576-1056%2F)",
            "priceHistory": [{
                "price": {
                    "value": "1195",
                    "currency": "NOK"
                },
                "date": 1473477532181
            }],
            "modified": 1473477532181,
            "inStock": 1,
            "sourceProductId": "441576-1056",
            "programLogo": "http://hst.tradedoubler.com/file/17833/2014-logos/200X200.png",
            "programName": "Nelly NO",
            "id": "57d37b9ce4b085c06c38c96b"
        }],
        "categories": [{
            "name": "Kvinne > KLÆR > Jeans > Straight"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "501 CT Jeans For Women",
        "productImage": {
            "url": "http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/441576-6581.jpg"
        },
        "language": "no",
        "description": "Jeans fra Levi's. Noe kortere nederst, fem lommer. Normal høyde på midjen, med hemper i linningen og knappegylfen. Dekorative slitte partier foran og nederst på benet.<br />Laget av 100% bomull.",
        "brand": "Levis",
        "identifiers": {
            "sku": "441576-6581"
        },
        "fields": [{
            "name": "sale",
            "value": "false"
        }, {
            "name": "artNumber",
            "value": "441576-6581"
        }, {
            "name": "productStyle",
            "value": "Straight"
        }, {
            "name": "gender",
            "value": "Kvinne"
        }, {
            "name": "extraImageProductLarge",
            "value": "http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/productLarge/441576-6581.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "extraImageProductSmall",
            "value": "http://nlyscandinavia.scene7.com/is/image/nlyscandinavia/cart_thumb/441576-6581.jpg"
        }, {
            "name": "productGroup",
            "value": "Jeans"
        }, {
            "name": "product_id_original",
            "value": "441576-6581"
        }, {
            "name": "productClass",
            "value": "Klær"
        }, {
            "name": "color",
            "value": "Desert"
        }, {
            "name": "sizes",
            "value": "W24/L32,W25/L32,W26/L32,W27/L32,W28/L32,W29/L32,W30/L32,W31/L32,W25/L34,W26/L34,W27/L34,W28/L34,W29/L34,W30/L34,W31/L34"
        }],
        "offers": [{
            "feedId": 10086,
            "productUrl": "http://pdt.tradedoubler.com/click?a(2402331)p(80279)product(57b3cafbe4b06cf59bc254bf)ttid(3)url(http%3A%2F%2Fnelly.com%2Fno%2Fkl%C3%A6r-til-kvinner%2Fkl%C3%A6r%2Fjeans%2Flevis-441%2F501-ct-jeans-for-women-441576-6581%2F)",
            "priceHistory": [{
                "price": {
                    "value": "1195",
                    "currency": "NOK"
                },
                "date": 1471400699283
            }],
            "modified": 1471400699283,
            "inStock": 1,
            "sourceProductId": "441576-6581",
            "programLogo": "http://hst.tradedoubler.com/file/17833/2014-logos/200X200.png",
            "programName": "Nelly NO",
            "id": "57b3cafbe4b06cf59bc254bf"
        }],
        "categories": [{
            "name": "Kvinne > KLÆR > Jeans > Straight"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: There is lot of unrelated code in here. Can you reduce this to a runnable peace of code that shows the error?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce this problem in a reduced test case. All I have is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c43887a995102566888e649392a3d54 but it's nowhere near.

Comment: You could always put the rake task in an empty rails app and test it there though.

Comment: So if you have a piece of code that does not show the error then you are close to the solution:-)

Comment: Funny. But hey, any chance you can help me with the reduced test case? Don't know what I'm doing wrong here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11e397b7ea1067035231e1c625455da1

Comment: I'll give it a try. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve...  but will make some proposals.

Comment: Here is what I'm trying to achieve: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/23bcf741b672da31cc8cb1ef8aa400df - thanks for breaking up the current script but is that really neccessary when the only real problem is accessing `product_group`?

Comment: As for the prices, I don't know. The JSON is pretty consistent, here's a fuller version of it: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/1e2735c257c174e36e27c242a0d853e6

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.3, yeah. Reason I prettified the JSON keys was purely cosmetic, but Hashie has made the code a lot prettier. Your example looks decent and nicely structured but at the same time it brought in with it the mess from the JSON.

Comment: Besides that I think my version is much cleaner and easier to read, test, understand, extend, maintain (which is just an opinion)... it also seems to work and extract the category just fine.

Comment: Well it sure is completely different! And supersimplified. I like it, thanks!

Comment: Added it all into the rake file now but it errors out, any clues? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb107a548c509e276506e51c945f573b

Comment: The response from RestClient seems to be a String, you need to parse it. Also the way you construct the URL is not correct. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Great stuff man! It works with `q: 'Jeans', limit: 10, token: 'XXX'`, but how to get it to query the actual categories? `q: URI.encode(@category), limit: 10, token: 'XXX'` returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Also, how come you don't use `dig` yourself? Wouldn't it make the code prettier?

Comment: Please check again, I updated the fetching part. I've made a mistake in my previous sample.

Comment: Unfortunately `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'json' for main:Object`: https://gist.github.com/02377f50c3fe17deb0e8dbc6d2e73475 -- note I changed the `CategoryFilter` line.

Comment: json parsing was missing.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I'm getting this error now: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46705a54bcd224ce28847ccd95fb214c

Comment: Here is the demo.rake that I used: https://gist.github.com/aa0ed620a72437687483adeb675ac06b -- did you get a chance to run it as well?

Comment: By the way, only products that have the field name "gender" whose value is "Kvinne" (meaning woman) should be included.

Comment: Feels like I'm doing your job?

Comment: Feels like our collaboration has hit a dead end. I appreciate your help though. I should be able to take it from here. Cheers!

Comment: Just open a new question with code that shows the problem. It's kind of hard to help otherwise.

Comment: Can we at least get your current code working first? The last three lines doesn't output anything. After that I'll create a new question regarding the extra filtering.

Comment: Just change the `CategoryFilter` to filter for something that is actually there, like "Vesker"

Comment: I am, but products is still 0 (https://gist.github.com/aa0ed620a72437687483adeb675ac06b).

Comment: The second argument of the `CategoryFilter` is a variable length argument in my code. So either remove the `*` in `CategoryFilter#initialize` method signature or add one when calling with an array: 
`CategoryFilter.new(products, *categories)`

Comment: We have it working. Awesome work man, thank you !!

Comment: Would it be possible starting a chat with you? I'm having some issues with this code and no idea how to reduce / isolate it to something others can understand. I will pay you ofcourse..

Comment: Basically I need to create the categories within Solidus first before I can start mass importing the products. But I have no idea how to output the categories as hashes from either the predefined array or the filtered JSON..

Comment: probably i'll be online around 22:00 CEST

Comment: Cool. Hopefully we should be able to "start a chat" here on SO once you come online.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to go to bed now (23:00 CEST), must up early tomorrow, got this new job at this elderly care center. I've outlined my problems as best as I can at https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/23bcf741b672da31cc8cb1ef8aa400df if you're able to have a look.

Comment: Shoot me an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of things going on in your code sample. I tried to split in parts and restructure it. It does not do the same as your code but I think it should get you started and perhaps you can come back when you have a more specific question.

Note that I did not use hashie, I think that accessing some deeply nested hash structures in a few places does not justify adding a new library to a project.

**Questions/Ideas/Hints:**

- are prices Integers or Floats?
- Is the JSON consistent (all elements present all the time?)
- Are you using Ruby 2.3? Then look into `Hash#dig`
- Why did you prettify the JSON keys? Does not make sense to me as you build `Product` objects to work with anyway?
- Unless there are performance issues i would convert all products to Ruby objects first and filter then. Just easier and more readable.

**Code**

**Product** (same as yours)

```
Product = Struct.new(:category, :name, :image, :price, :description)
```

**JsonProductBuilder** converts the parsed JSON to Product Objects.

```
class JsonProductBuilder
  def initialize(json)
    @json = json
  end

  def call
    json.fetch('products', []).map do |item|
      Product.new(
        extract_category(item),
        item['name'],
        item.fetch('productImage', {})['url'],
        extract_price(item),
        item['description']
      )
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :json

  def extract_category(item)
    field = item['fields'].find do |field|
      field['name'] == 'productGroup'
    end
    field['value'] if field
  end

  def extract_price(item)
    offer = item['offers'].first
    history = offer['priceHistory'].first
    value = history['price']['value']
    Integer(value) # Or use Float?
  end
end
```

**CategoryFilter** returns a limited subset of the products. You can easily add other filters and combine them. Perhaps you might want to look into `lazy` for performance improvements.

```
class CategoryFilter
  def initialize(products, *categories)
    @products = products
    @categories = categories
  end

  def call
    products.select do |product|
      categories.include?(product.category)
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :products, :categories
end
```

**Use it like this:**

```
limit = 10
categories = ['laptop', 'something']
params = {
  q: categories.join(','),
   limit: limit,
 }

 paramsString = params.map do |key, value|
   "#{key}=#{value}"
 end.join(';')

 response = RestClient.get(
   "http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/products.json;#{paramsString}?token=#{token}"
  )

json = JSON.parse(response)
products = JsonProductBuilder.new(json).call
puts products.size

products = CategoryFilter.new(products, 'Klær', 'Sko', 'Jeans').call
puts products.size

products.each do |product|
  puts product.to_h
end
```